# How can I create a Package on a memory stream

Tags: .net-3.5, openxml, packaging

Is it possible to create a System.IO.Packaging.Package on a memory stream. I'd like to avoid the file system and do everything in memory if possible.

However, the only way to create a Package is to call Package.Open which accepts a stream. 
However, if the stream is empty, this fails.

Any clue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works:

```
Stream memStream = new MemoryStream();
Package pack = Package.Open(memStream, FileMode.Create);
```